# Not able to get JWT header in Istio custom AuthorizationPolicy passed via outputPayloadToHeader of RequestAuthentication

Tags: jwt, istio

We have kubernetese cluster deployed on AWS EKS with Istio 1.11.4.
We are using JWT for authentication and passing it in the header `x-jwt-assertion`.
To validate the JWT we are using [Istio RequestAuthentication](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/request_authentication/).
Here is the definition

```
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "RequestAuthentication"
metadata:
  name: "graphql-jwt"
  namespace: graphql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: graphql
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: "https://login.<mycompany>.io/"
      jwksUri: "https://<mycompany>.us.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
      outputPayloadToHeader: "my-data"
      fromHeaders:
        - name: x-jwt-assertion
          prefix: "Bearer "
```

We have another service deployed in the cluster that determines based on the request headers and body whether the request should be forwarded or not. We are using Istio CUSTOM [Authorization Policy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/) for this.
The definition for the AuthorizationPolicy is as following

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: ext-auth-my
spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: graphql
  action: CUSTOM
  provider:
    name: my-ext-auth
  rules:
    - { }
```

The configurations for this AuthorizationPolicy are defined in the `istio` configmap under the `istio-system` namespace. The configurations are specified below

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mesh: |-
    extensionProviders:
    - name: "my-ext-auth"
      envoyExtAuthzHttp:
        service: "my-api-svc.foo.svc.cluster.local"
        port: "8080"
        pathPrefix: "/hasaccess"
        includeRequestHeadersInCheck: ["my-data", "content-type"]
        includeRequestBodyInCheck:
          maxRequestBytes: 1000000
```

Now in my service (my-api-svc.foo.svc.cluster.local:8080/hasaccess) I am not getting the `my-data` header. If I change the value of `includeRequestHeadersInCheck` and remove `content-type`, my service throws an error of invalid mime type, and if I replace `my-data` with `x-jwt-assertion` the request doesn't make it through to my service and I get `Jwt issuer is not configured`. So this validates that the headers are getting detected, its for some reason just not making through to my service.

The headers that make it to my service are

```
x-request-id
x-b3-parentspanid
x-b3-traceid
x-b3-spanid
x-forwarded-client-cert
x-b3-sampled
X-Forwarded-Proto
X-Forwarded-For
Host
Content-Length
Content-Type
```

I am not able to figure out why `my-data`header is not making its way to my api which is to Authorize the request. This header does reach the destination service for which the request was intended for, so it's not getting lost.

Comment: Is it my-date or my-data ?

Comment: it is my-data, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Not sure why, but I was able to resolve this by putting my JWT in the `Authorization` header and adding `forwardOriginalToken: true` in the RequestAuthentication and then adding it to `includeRequestHeadersInCheck`

Comment: If you solved your question, you can post [your own answer and accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Don't forget to add details, so it will be helpful for other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding my JWT token in Authorization header instead of x-jwt-assertion and using the forwardOriginalToken property in my RequestAuthentication.

So now RequestAuthentication is

```
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "RequestAuthentication"
metadata:
  name: "graphql-jwt"
  namespace: graphql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: graphql
  jwtRules:
    - issuer: "https://login.<mycompany>.io/"
      jwksUri: "https://<mycompany>.us.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
      outputPayloadToHeader: "my-data"
      forwardOriginalToken: true
      fromHeaders:
        - name: Authorization
          prefix: "Bearer "
```

and my istio configmap is

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mesh: |-
    extensionProviders:
    - name: "my-ext-auth"
      envoyExtAuthzHttp:
        service: "my-api-svc.foo.svc.cluster.local"
        port: "8080"
        pathPrefix: "/hasaccess"
        includeRequestHeadersInCheck: ["Authorization", "content-type"]
        includeRequestBodyInCheck:
          maxRequestBytes: 1000000
```

For further details [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/35941) is the link to the github discussion.